# Linking c++ code: undefined reference to `Student::Student(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linker-errors, gnu, clion

Every time I build my code I get this error. I tried different projects and it's the same thing. It appeared in vscode and CLion; however I tried the code on <Relp.it> and it was working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student{

private:
    std::string name;
    double grade;

public:
    //public constructor to reach it
    Student (std::string s, double g);

    void setName(std::string n){
        name = n;
    }

    void setGrade(double g){
        grade = g;
    }

    std::string pass(){
        //if grade greater than 60 print "yes" if not print "no"
        return (grade > 60 ? "yes": "no");
    }

    void printStatus(){
        cout << "name:" << name << endl;
        cout << "grade: " << grade << endl;
        cout << "Pass: " << pass() << endl; 
        cout << endl;
    }

};



int main(){

    Student Barrak("Barrak", 96);
    Barrak.printStatus();
    Barrak.pass();


    return 0;
};
```

and this is what i get.

```
PS C:\Users\barra\Desktop\ab> cd "c:\Users\barra\Desktop\ab\" ; if ($?) { g++ main.cpp -o main } ; if ($?) { .\main }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\barra\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1itdQl.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `Student::Student(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\barra\Desktop\ab>
```

Comment: If it was working on Repl.it, then probably there is a problem there and you should report the problem, so that it can be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that you've only **declared** the parameterized constructor `Student (std::string s, double g);` but not **defined** it. So the linker cannot find it when needed and hence gives the mentioned error.

To **solve** this problem you can add the definition for this constructor as shown below:

```
class Student{

private:
   //other members as before

public:
    //DECLARATION FOR PARAMETERIZED CONSTRUCTOR
    Student (std::string s, double g);

    //other members as before

};

//DEFINE PARAMETERIZED CONSTRUCTOR
Student::Student (std::string s, double g): name(s), grade(g) //this uses constructor initializer list to initiliaze name and grade
{
    
}
```

The output of the modified program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ecKCMtNtt).

**Method 2**

You can also define the parameterized constructor inside the class in which case it will be implicitly inline as shown below:

```
class Student{

private:
    std::string name;
    double grade;

public:
    //DEFINITION FOR PARAMETERIZED CONSTRUCTOR
    Student (std::string s, double g): name(s), grade(g)
    {
        
    }

    //other members as before

};
```